# A working example of a Virtual List in Framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

I've been head banging for two days trying to get a virtual list to work in Framework7. Is there a simple example of this anywhere or would someone be kind enough to post the code for a virtual list.

I've read the [Framework7 docs](https://framework7.io/docs/virtual-list.html) over at least 10 times and tried many different ways of placing the code that is in the docs. I've also looked at the [tutorial reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/framework7/virtual_list.htm). NEITHER shows an actual script demonstration of how to really do this. I think framework7 is an amazing piece of work, but I am just trying to learn it. I'm not knowledgeable of a lot of javascript. Much of the documentation is very good, however,some of the more difficult and challenging things for newbies like me leave much to be desired.

I've also scoured stackoverflow, there are a few questions on virtual lists but nothing as trivial as what I need help with and no examples of code that show the a completely working example.

Where do I place the javascript for the virtual list? I've tried putting it into myApp.js and into the html on the page with a script tag.

I've placed the following in the DOM of my page as instructed via the docs:

```
    <!-- Virtual List -->
<div class="list-block virtual-list">
  <!-- keep it empty -->
</div>
```

What I don't understand where to put this code or if more coding is needed to get this working...

```
    var myList = app.virtualList('.list-block', {
    items: [1,2,3,4],
    height: 44
});
```

Anyone?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried putting it inside a onPageInit: `myApp.onPageInit('*', function(page){ if(page.name=='your-page-name'){ /* your code here */ }});`

Answer (score 0):

you could try step below ,  it is work in my project

1. html code

   ```
    <div id="no-margin-top" class="list-block media-list ">
      <div class="list-group list-virtual virtual-list"/>  
   </div>
   ```
2. Initiate virtual list ,please also add parameter "renderItem" with html template

   ```
    var myList = app.virtualList('.list-virtual', {
           // Array with items data
           items: [],
           height:132,
           rowsAfter:20,
           // Custom render function to render item's HTML
           renderItem: function (index, item) {
               return '<li class="browsing-item" id="item-' + item.id_event + '" data-id="' + item.id_event + '">' +

                               '<div class="item-subtitle" data-id="' + item.id_event + '">' + item.name + '</div>' +
                               '<div class="item-subtitle" data-id="' + item.id_event + '">' + item.address + '</div>' +

                       '</li>'
           }
       });
   ```
3. fill myList with related array object, like example below (using method "appendItem")

   for (var i = 0; i < data.data_event.length; i++) {
       myList.appendItem(data.data_event[i]);
   }

Comment: @pargata But... where do I put this code? "var myList = app.virtualList('.list-virtual'..." I don't know where or how to set the virtual list code up. I've placed it in my app.js but nothing works. I can't figure out how to wire everything together. Thank you for replying. It is very hard to get help with Framework7.

Comment: In the myApp.js... I've tried so many ways of inserting this. This one doesn't work either:`myApp.onPageInit('myPage', function (page) {
    // run createContentPage func after link was clicked
    var myList = app.virtualList('.list-block', {
    items: [1,2,3,4],
    height: 44
    }); 
 
});`

Comment: have you try this ,,, $(document).on('pageBeforeInit', function (e) { //put code here    });

Comment: Thank you again. I've spent two more days trying to understand how to use this simple feature. Wish the documents had just a simple example: html page and myApp.js page so that I could see how/where it should go. I'll keep looking and trying. I appreciate your trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this code into your route.js file 
{
    path: '/mainapp/',
    async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
          // Router instance
          var router = this;

```
      // App instance
      var app = router.app;

      // Simulate Ajax Request
      setTimeout(function () {
        // We got user data from request
        var items = [];      
          app.request.promise.json('Url in the server')
          .then(function (res) {  
            for (var i in res.data){
                var foo = res.data[i].id 
         ...
                items.push({
                  title: foo ,

                })
            }
            return{
              items: items
            }
          });

        // Resolve route to load page
        resolve(
          {
            url: './pages/foo.html',
          },
          {
            on:{
              pageBeforeRemove:function(){

                app.virtualList.destroy();
              },
              pageInit:function(){
               var self = this.$app
                app.virtualList = app.virtualList.create({
                  // List Element
                  el: '.virtual-list',
                  // Pass array with items
                  items: items,
                  // List item Template7 template
                  itemTemplate:

                  //Put your html here and make sure you add template7 expressions like so <h1>{{this.title}}</h1>
                });
              }
            },
          }

        );
    }, 1000);
}
```

},